# The crontab does not execute the instruction to generate the copy of the mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to execute an instruction that allows to generate a backup copy of a database hosted in mysql. This statement executes correctly when I execute it directly outside crontab, but being inside crontab it does not generate the backup.

```
mysqldump --defaults-file="/home/administrador/.credenciales.cnf" wmszf > /mysql/backups/wms/wmszf-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M).sql
```

I also tried to test with a different instruction, and validate if the cron was executing the instructions correctly and this instruction executed normally

```
* * * * * mysqldump --defaults-file="/home/administrador/.credenciales.cnf" wmszf > /mysql/backups/wms/wmszf-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M).sql
```

You can see that I have all the minutes to verify every moment if something has happened, when I achieve it, I will modify the frequency so that it is done every day at 6:00 p.m.

I appreciate your collaboration.

Comment: [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: Before each % for the date format, place an escape symbol `\` (backslash) to indicate that the % symbol is part of the string rather than to generate a line break.

```
50 17 * * * mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/administrador/.credenciales.cnf wmszf > /mysql/backups/wms/wmszf-$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y_\%H-\%M).sql
```